# Share codeigniter session from database on two different domain in one server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have two websites with Codeigniter on one server with two different databases,

for example I have mydom.com  and mydom2.com and set my config.php on mydom.com as below :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'mydom.ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = false;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = false;
```

and the mydom2 config.php :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'mydom.ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = false;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = false;
```

both of them are same, mydom2 is connected to mydom database in line sess_save_path. 
Session is working , but they are different , when I login in mydom , session is set , but on mydom2 it is not set. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197089/discussion-between-morteza-rastgoo-and-nima-habibkhoda).

Answer (score 1):

I think You should try with change cookie name and sessions saved table name. Reference link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: i think at all it is not secure ,  the solution that i design , is switch database connection with new session that will post between two domain and create a new session , the best algorithm is to destroy last session and create another session with new data , it is secure and easy to use